# Cross Navigation Between XAML Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two XAML pages that are each part of a different MVVM pattern; call them PageA and PageB.  Each MVVM framework is in a different namespace and project, since there is no cooperation between them; call them SpaceA and SpaceB, and ProjectA and ProjectB.

Except: At some point the SpaceA framework would like to navigate to PageB, and at another point, SpaceB would like to navigate to PageA.
The obvious challenge is that this (inevitably?) causes a circular reference between the frameworks:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SpaceA.PageA)); /* circular */ Frame.Navigate(typeof(SpaceB.PageB));
```

<< The original form of this question didn't have code, which probably made it too vague or broad.  So I've added it.>>

Here's the code for PageA:

```
<Page x:Class="SpaceA.PageA" ...><Button Tapped="onTap">Go to Page B</Button>
```

With CodeBehind

```
namespace SpaceA
{
    public sealed partial class PageA : Page
    {
    private void onTap(...) { Frame.Navigate(typeof(SpaceB.PageB)); }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for PageB:

```
<Page x:Class="SpaceB.PageB" ...><Button Tapped="onTap">Go to Page A</Button>
```

With CodeBehind

```
namespace SpaceB
{
    public sealed partial class PageB : Page
    {
    private void onTap(...) { Frame.Navigate(typeof(SpaceA.PageA)); }
    }
}
```

I've left out all of the (reasonably complex) logic in the VM and Model elements for simplicity.  But there's no coupling between them, except that the pages call each other.  The above won't assemble, because of the circular dependency.

There are several solutions that I can see.

I could combine them all into the same namespace; but that seems a pity, since they're only coupled by this cross-navigation, which is the reason that I'd planned to have them in different assemblies.  Though perhaps I'm being too granular in my use of namespaces?

Or I could do something fancy by having a dummy page above them both, in a third namespace that knows about SpaceA and SpaceB, so that the navigation is done via that dummy page.  But that seems ugly, since I'd have to correct the back/forward navigation stack, I would imagine.

Or maybe move the Pages themselves into their own, shared space, say SpacePage, and then leave the rest of the MVVM pattern in their respective spaces?

But it seems as though this should be a common pattern, and should have been addressed more cleanly than any of the above.

Comment: Too broad as asked, especially without a good [mcve] (but probably would be even with one). That said, for this sort of mutually-referencing scenario, your goal should be to fix the code so that neither class depends on the other _class_ per se. Your navigation should be abstracted so that at run-time, a controller class that knows both page classes can set the page in each, which that page should navigate to, to the other page.

Comment: Hi @Peter, I'm not convinced that the example as set out isn't M, C, and V; I could add the code but the patterns are so well known that it seems superfluous.  That being said, your suggestion is helpful.  MVVM doesn't have a Controller class, as you know, but I think in the end your suggestion devolves to putting everything in the same namespace.  And maybe thats the best solution.  Doesn't seem elegant though.

Comment: You don't need an official "controller" object (though frankly, you should probably not worry too much about being so constrained to a specific design pattern). Just some place in the code that knows about both pages and is responsible for configuring/initializing them. My suggestion has _nothing_ to do with namespaces, nor would that address the issue anyway (you can have the classes in the same namespace but still declared in two different assemblies). I won't debate the question of [mcve], as the actual definition of MCVE is well-understood and not at all what's provided here.

Comment: Hi @Peter.  I've added code to the question; hopefully that helps - sorry if it wasn't clear before.  When you say "some place in the code that knows about both pages" could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was confusing the semantics of namespaces and projects.

There is no problem having each MVVM in a different namespace; the problem is then having each in a different project.  The solution is to move them all the same project, ideally in separate folders to maintain the structure.